# Service operation GetCategories is unknown

Tags: xml, jsonp, translate, ebay-api

Ebay supports a few ways of doing an API call including Name-Value pairs and XML. Almost all examples are in XML. 
Please help me translate the following XML code into JSONP URL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetCategoriesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>ABC...123</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <CategorySiteID>0</CategorySiteID>
    <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
</GetCategoriesRequest>
```

I came up with this URL

```
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1
?SECURITY-APPNAME=DmitryKh-8c0f-4272-80d0-a0df7dca76f8
&OPERATION-NAME=GetCategories
&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0
&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON
&callback=_cb_findCategories
&REST-PAYLOAD
&CategorySiteID=0
&DetailLevel=ReturnAll
```

But it gives me error message "Service operation GetCategories is unknown"

`/**/_cb_findCategories({"errorMessage":[{"error":[{"errorId":["2000"],"domain":["CoreRuntime"],"severity":["Error"],"category":["Request"],"message":["Service operation GetCategories is unknown"],"subdomain":["Inbound_Meta_Data"],"exceptionId":["com.ebay.soaframework.common.exceptions.ServiceException"],"parameter":[{"@name":"Param1","__value__":"GetCategories"}]}]}]})`

Comment: Closely all `ebay-api` questions are unanswered in here -.-.